# How to save and load GKGameModelPlayer from Realm in Swift?

Tags: swift, realm, gameplay-kit

I am attempting to implement a `GKGameModel` in my application.   In it, it holds variables to a few things, but for the purposes of my question I'm interested in the following two variables:

```
import GameplayKit
final class GameModel: NSObject, GKGameModel {
    var players: [GKGameModelPlayer]?
    var activePlayer: GKGameModelPlayer?
}
```

I do something like this to initialise the game with 3 players (not exact)

```
let game = GameModel.init()
game.players = [Player(),Player(),Player()] // Create 3 players
guard let firstPlayer = game.players.first else {
     return
}
game.activePlayer = firstPlayer
```

A player class is defined as:

```
class Player : NSObject, GKGameModelPlayer {
    var playerId: Int // GKGameModelPlayer protocol variable
    let name: String
    var cash: Int = 0
}
```

In my project I have Realm Entities and the models seperated.   So there will be a `PlayerEntity` and a `Player` class.

I'm wanting to use `RealmSwift` to save and load the `GKGameModelPlayer` data, and more specifically the ability to store/re-store the active player.

I think the key here is the `playerId` variable; but I am not sure.

But what I'm not sure about is retrieving this information and then re-mapping it into a valid `GKGameModelPlayer` format

My current idea/theory is that I need to map my model to an entity class and vice-versa.

Ie:

```
// [REALM] Player entity
class PlayerEntity: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var playerId: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var cash: Int = 0

    override static func primaryKey() -> String {
       return "id"
    }
}
```

And then I extend this class to do some "mapping":

```
extension PlayerEntity {
    // Map model -> entity
    convenience init(model: Player) {
        self.init()

        self.playerId = model.playerId
        self.name = model.name
        self.cash = model.cash
    }
}

extension Player {
    // Map entity -> model
    convenience init(entity: PlayerEntity) {
        let playerId = entity.playerId
        let name = entity.name
        let cash = entity.cash

        self.init(id: playerId, name: name, cash: cash)
    }
}
```

Right now, the `playerId` is always zero (0) because I'm not really sure how to set it.

I can save a player to realm.

The issue comes from when I try to restore the player, and I want to restore the activePlayer variable in the `GameModel`

Therefore, my question is:

How would I go about saving and restoring the `activePlayer` variable so that it continues to comply to `GKGameModelPlayer`?

I appreciate any assistance on this.

With thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could use those extensions, sometimes simpler is better. Here's a rough example:

```
class PlayerEntity: Object {
    @objc dynamic var playerId: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var cash: Int = 0

    convenience init(withPlayer: PlayerClass) {
       self.init()
       self.playerId = withPlayer.playerId
       self.name = withPlayer.name
       self.cash = withPlayer.cash
    }

    func getPlayer() -> Player {
       let p = Player()
       p.playerId = self.playerId
       p.name = self.name
       p.cash = self.cash
       return p
    }

    override static func primaryKey() -> String {
       return "playerId"
    }
}
```

to load all the players into an array... this will do it

```
let playerResults = realm.objects(PlayerEntity.self)
for player in playerResults {
   let aPlayer = player.getPlayer()
   self.playerArray.append(aPlayer)
}
```

Notice the removal of

```
@objc dynamic var id = UUID().uuidString
```

because it's not really being used to identify the object as a primary key.

The primary key is really

```
var playerId: Int // GKGameModelPlayer protocol variable
```

which is fine to use as long as it's unique.

Comment: I understand, i think i just overcomplicate things.  i will give it  a go.   i think i can save and load the activeplayer reference by first relying on the playerid, or if i have a turn index reference and then setting the active player from this reference  i will write some tests to see if i can do it

Comment: @zardon Excellent. Let us know if you get stuck.